# Python using(parsing) a textbox value as string into a function

Tags: python, string, variables, textbox, tkinter

```
url=StringVar()
txt1=Entry(root,textvariable=url)
txt1.pack()

button1 = Button(root, text="Download" ,command=downloadFile)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

ok this is my basic GUI... I have a textbox txt1 which i want to use in the function below

```
def downloadFile():
    #print "url is:",url
    file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
```

My aim is to feed in the URL in the textbox and then split the URL in my function downloadfile(), but my url variable becomes PY_VAR0 instead of "www.example.com/file.exe"

and the error message I get is "StringVar instance has no attribute split" 
I am doing something very wrong but i don't know where.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringVar is just a "Value holder for strings variables". To get its content (the string) use:

```
StringVar.get() # Return value of variable as string.
```

printing the StringVar directly ("print url") invokes:

```
StringVar.__str__() # Return the name of the variable in Tcl.
```

which will return the internal variable name, not its value. in your code use:

```
file_name = url.get().split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: please help with this https://pastebin.com/uPWyPXMZ and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767638/how-to-pass-a-textbox-entry-to-variables-using-tkinter-in-python