# How to pass a textbox entry to variables using tkinter in python

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, textbox

I have some fairly simple code to get values for a urlstring.

I have looked at all the other questions and cant seem to find a relevant answer I can apply

Some of the code comes up first in the Ipython console which I expect and will change later and I do get a value in Ipython console from the hardcoded variables on button press but cant seem to get value of text boxes into the variables and then use them instead?

```
amount = '1'
cur1 = input('What Currency would you like to trade from? ')
cur2 = input('What Currency would you like to trade to? ')
cur1_1 = StringVar()
cur2_1 = StringVar()
#i = 0 


#Textboxes for user input
txtcur1 = Entry(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold",bg="white", width=6, textvariable=cur1_1)
txtcur1.place(x=110, y=50)
txtcur2 = Entry(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold",bg="white", width=6, textvariable=cur2_1)
txtcur2.place(x=110, y=75)
#End


def results():
    t = datetime.utcnow()  
    url1  = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amount + "&From=" + cur1 + "&To=" + cur2
    url2 = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amount + "&From=" + cur2_1 + "&To=" + cur1_1
```

But for the life of me I cant get the variables from the textboxes into the variables `cur1_1` and `cur2_1` and am getting the typeerror.

```
url2 = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amount + "&From=" + cur2_1 + "&To=" + cur1_1
TypeError: must be str, not StringVar
```

When I change it to string it says must be 3 digit long
I would have thought It would have been a bit simpler than this.
Any help please?

Also once I have the returned values for the exchange rates I need them to be converted to a `decimal to 9` places and displayed with commas for monetary use .

Full code here https://pastebin.com/uPWyPXMZ

Comment: You've posted too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]

Comment: i did try but it got too confusing

Comment: and i have seen much longer ones when researching other questions like this

Comment: THROWS COMPUTER AT WALL IN FRUSTRATION

Comment: could you give me an example of what that would look like to you with this code instead of just saying i should do it... tell someone to get it right or show someone how to get it right which one do you think teaches people better?

Comment: If your question is about passing variables from a text box to a variable, all you need is a text box and a variable, and a few more  lines to tie it all together. We don't need any of the beautiful soup code, it's completely irrelevant. As for which approach is better, I would argue that teaching someone how to ask a question that is easy to understand, easy to reproduce, and easy to answer is the best help I can give you, because it will pay off for the rest of your career. Knowing how to ask good questions is an important skill to learn.

Comment: Thanx Bryan I agree I need to learn I was attempting to show some simple code but thought I needed to show what I was thinking about

Comment: Please view @skrx

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be you're using `cur1_1` and `cur2_1` as if they were strings when you should be calling their `StringVar.get()` methods to access their string values.

A simple-minded example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_text():
    label_text.set('Heh, heh, heh, you said, "' + entry_text.get() + '"')

root = tk.Tk()

entry_text = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=entry_text)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=show_text)
button.pack()

label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Put text in the entry box, and click the button.  The text will be transfered from the entry box to the label via the `.get()` method of the `StringVar` associated with the `Entry` when it was created.

Comment: to convert the return vals to decimals simply      returned_val = Decimal (thevalue.get())???

Comment: @GoulouhAnwar, I would say `int(thevalue.get())` or `float(thevalue.get())` depending what you need.  From where are you importing `Decimal()`?

Comment: from decimal import Decimal havent added yet \

Comment: I have aprivate chat between myself and skrx I would be honored if you would join if yu felt like answering my n00b questions karma is always karma